# ORA-01858 Error Message

Tags: sql, oracle, date, format

I have a question regarding date format error. So i have this query

```
SELECT TO_DATE (PS.PROJECT_START_DT, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

and gives me **ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected**

my table structure is this

```
PROJECT_START_DT PROJECT_END_DT JOB_NAME
2/5/2015         4/2/2015       W-IGG
2/18/2015        3/19/2015      W14056
2/5/2015         3/31/2015      W14013
```

Please help me with my issue with date format

Comment: Is `project_start_dt` a `date`?  Or a `varchar2`?  If it is a `date`, as the name implies, why are you calling `to_date`?  Are you just trying to truncate the time component?

Comment: yes it is a date....

Comment: my intention is just showing the date thru select statement which further i will use it for processing some data

Comment: Do you want to select a `date`?  Or do you want to select a `varchar2` in a particular format?  If you want to select a `date`, just select the `date`.

Comment: If `PROJECT_START_DT` the applying `to_date()` is totally useless. As `to_date()` expects a `VARCHAR` parameter Oracle will first convert your date into a varchar (using a default format defined by your NLS settings), then the `to_date()` will convert that varchar back into a date (what it was to begin with).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SELECT TO_DATE (PS.PROJECT_START_DT, 'MM/DD/YYYY')

It makes no sense to use **TO_DATE** over a DATE column. You need **TO_CHAR** to display in the desired format using a proper **FORMAT MODEL**.

```
SQL> SELECT to_date(SYSDATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy') FROM dual;
SELECT to_date(SYSDATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy') FROM dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected


SQL>
SQL> SELECT to_char(SYSDATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(SY
----------
02/06/2015

SQL>
```

The DATE datatype has both date and time elements,

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(SYSDATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt_tm FROM dual;

DT_TM
-------------------
02/06/2015 11:28:32

SQL>
```

If you want to use the **DATE** value in any date operation, then you don't have to convert it into anything at all, simply use the DATE value directly for date operations.

**Update** On OP's request about the query here http://pastie.org/9891465

In that query, you don't have to use `TO_CHAR` in the **sub-query**. Use `TO_CHAR` only in the main select since that is what will display the values. The **start_date** and **end_dt** in the sub-query is an INPUT to the outer query and should remain as **DATE** values and need not **convert** it into a **string**.

```
SELECT LEVEL WEEK_NUM_INCR,
  TO_CHAR (start_date + (LEVEL - 1) * 7, 'WW') WEEK_POSITION
  /* WEEK POSITION FOR THE WHOLE YEAR */
  ,
  TO_CHAR (start_date + (LEVEL - 1) * 7, 'MM/DD/YYYY') START_WEEK_DATE,
  TO_CHAR (start_date + (LEVEL) * 7, 'MM/DD/YYYY') END_WEEK_DATE
FROM
  (SELECT PS.PROJECT_START_DT start_date,
    PS.PROJECT_END_DT end_date
  FROM PROJECT_SPAN PS
  WHERE PS.JOB_NAME = 'W-IGG'
  )
  CONNECT BY start_date + (LEVEL - 1) * 7 < end_date;
```

Comment: lalit if i use TO_CHAR, its gonna be a problem in this query snippet  http://pastie.org/9891465

Comment: In that query, ther eis no need to use `TO_CHAR` in the sub-query, simply select start_date, end_dt and use `to_char` in the main select. Let me  update my answer.